# Test Google billing in android api <24 using android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I've created an app which uses Google Billing for in app purchases. I've tested the functionality on a number of real devices, as well as on emulators in Android Studio and it appears to be working fine.

I don't have any real devices that are running lower than android API 24, and although I can create a virtual device in Android Studio, it doesn't look like I can create one with Google play store functionality.

If I pick a device with Play store functionality...
[image]

...I'm only shown recommended system images down to API 24 (the same is true regardless of which device I pick)...

[image]

I can see plenty of other images under the 'X86 images' and 'Other images' sections, but none with Play store functionality.

Having tested on other API's, I'm pretty sure this will work, but it would be nice to be sure. Is there any way I can be sure without purchasing a physical device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Official answer**: No, there is no way if you want a "trustful" test environment.
  Google has never released (and probably never will) emulator images with Google Play below API 24.
  If you want test your app with API below that level your only option is buying an old phone with Google Play installed.
- **Unofficial answer**: Online you can find some guide/tutorial which teach you how to install Play service and Play store on emulator images, like [this one](https://medium.com/@dai_shi/installing-google-play-services-on-an-android-studio-emulator-fffceb2c28a1) but I did not try them and don't know if they really works.